# How can I create a custom protocol like HTTP, FTP, accesible from browser?

Tags: python, networking, browser, protocols

I have my application which communicates over its own protocol, suppose if a user installs the application and want to get data, then he needs to use that protocol. Let my protocol be `XYZ` so the user is able to use the same from their existing browsers to get the data. Example: `XYZ://myApplication/Query`. I am not sure how can I achieve it. I should be noted that the application is running on the user's device itself.

Basically, I want to route a specific request to my application, and let the other request function normally. I am using python for the development of my application.

Additionally, If my approach is wrong then what can I do to create my own communication protocol which can be easily used with existing browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own scheme?
Only if you create the right backend server which can response to your request in your protocol, you can do it.
You can also find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344993/how-can-i-prepend-the-http-protocol-to-a-url-when-necessary).